# How to use laravel echo without webpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo

There is a limitation of bandwidth usage of my website.So I want get the Laravel Echo from a cdn server instead of my own server.
I tried in my test.blade.php

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2.1.0/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/laravel-echo@1.3.5/dist/echo.min.js"></script>

<script>

  import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
  window.io = require('socket.io-client');

  if (typeof io !== 'undefined') {
      window.Echo = new Echo({
          broadcaster: 'socket.io',
          host: 'http://www.test2.com:6001',
      });
  }


  window.Echo.private(`orderStatus-1`) // 私有频道
      .listen('.App\\Events\\OrderShipped', (e) => {
          console.log(e);
      });
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just include these codes in your app.blade.php

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2.1.1/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/glitterlip/echoexample/blob/master/public/js/echocompiled.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think you mean the raw github link:     
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glitterlip/echoexample/master/public/js/echocompiled.js